# Finding the particular integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

I'm getting the particular integral as (x+y)^3/36, but the answer is given to be (x+y)^2/36. Kindly help, and please do mention the steps invovled ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to verify that your solution is correct by calculating required derivatives. If $z=\frac{(x+y)^2}{36}$ (answer), then $z_{xx}= z_{yx}=z_{yy}=\frac{1}{18}$ and hence when you substituted into the equation you will see that it is not satisfied. On the other hand, if $z=\frac{(x+y)^3}{36}$ (your solution), then $z_{xx}=z_{yx}=z_{yy}=\frac{x+y}{6}$ and so $z_{xx}+3z_{yx}+2z_{yy}=x+y$. Besides this you can find other particular solutions, for instance, $z=\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{y^3}{12}$ is another solution.

Comment: Thanks, but how did you find the other solution ?

Comment: First of all I made a mistake I will edit it. We can find particular solutions depending on $x$ and $y$ by solving $z_{xx}=x$ and $2z_{yy}=y$ (integrating w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, respectively) gives $z_{p_1}=x^3/6$ and $z_{p_2}=y^3/12$ and set $z_p=z_{p_1}+z_{p_2}$. You see that the mixed derivative iz zero. Of course this setting depends on the function on the RHS. For general case you can use the operator method to find $z_p$: $z_p=\frac{1}{D^2_x+3D_xD_y+2D^2_y}(x+y)$.